# Range validator in asp.net doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this RV for a textbox in my page :

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="titleRV" runat="server" ControlToValidate="titletxt" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red" MinimumValue="4" MaximumValue="100" Type="Integer" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" >Must be more than 3 !</asp:RangeValidator>
```

when I type any number of characters in my textbox at runtime the range validator appears whether I typed less than 3 letters or not ,and if I increased the number of letters it doesn't disappear! any help please ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? A range validator is designed to check that you enter a value in a range - for example a number between 0 and 100. It sounds to me like you're trying to check how many letters were entered? You may have to use a RegEx validator.

Comment: use ^.{4,100}$ to select min4 max 100 char

Comment: @GunnerAziz ur pattern can be used for any aliphatical system ?

Comment: its not tested but should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A range validator is designed to check that you enter a value in a range - for example a number between 0 and 100. It sounds to me like you're trying to check how many letters were entered?

Assuming I've understood correctly my suggestion would be to use a RegEx validator.

You could use an expression like:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valLength" runat="server"    
    ErrorMessage="Your text must be between 3 and 100 characters"       
    ValidationExpression="^[0-9a-zA-Z]{3,}$"
    ControlToValidate="txtTextBox" />
```

This will obviously require tweaking depending on the characters you allow

Comment: is this pattern for English litters only ? @Liath

Comment: The example I've given is for upper and lowercase letters (a-z) and numbers (0-9) of at least three characters. I'd suggest creating a new question if you need help with the regex itself.

Comment: okay thanx very much , ur comments and answers clarified the problem to me @Liath

Comment: Great, glad we could help - you've got a wide range of answers here. Can you mark the one which helped you the most as the answer for future users?

Comment: I made a new question @Liath http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20951869/regex-pattern-for-any-alphapitc-system

Answer (score 2):

Rangevalidator is to check that the value entered falls between two values, not that it is a certain length. What you seem to be looking for are length validators

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" MaxLength="100" .../>
```

I don't think there is a minimum length validator built in, but you can easily add something in the code behind

```
if(txtTextBox.Length < 3)
    // display error message
```

or a regular expression validator

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valLength" runat="server"    
    ErrorMessage="Must be between 3 and 100 characters"
    ControlToValidate="txtTextBox"    
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9'@&#.\s]{3,100}$" />
```

Comment: this will be a server side validation .. I want it client side

Comment: @AyaMohammad a point of interest .NET validators actually validate both client side AND server side!

Comment: @Liath but I set the attribute (EnalbeClientScript) to true !

Comment: Sorry, my comment ws directed more at your original JS - I agree 100% with your suggestion of a RegEx validator

Answer (score 1):

Your range validator validates if the number is between 4 and 100, not the number of chars in the textbox.

This will do the trick (CustomValidator):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="titletxt" />    
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="titletxt"
    Text="The text length should be between 4 and 20" 
    ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>


<script type="text/javascript">
function clientValidate(sender, args) {
    if (args.Value.length < 4 ||args.Value.length > 20) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what's being validate you may also want to validate server side in case JS has been hacked/turned off

Comment: @Liath: Agreed, you will always need a server side check.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('titletxt').value.length < 3) {
document.getElementById('spMessage').style.display = '';
                return false;
            }
            else {
document.getElementById('spMessage').style.display = 'none';
                return true;
            }
        }
        </script>
```

HTML....

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="titletxt" onblur="return test()"></asp:TextBox>
<span id='spMessage' style="font-weight:bold; font-size:small; color:Red; display:none">Enter more than 3 char!</span>
```

You can create this javascript and Call test() function to validate textbox....

Comment: I don't want to popup an alert to the user